# Поддержка нескольких языков на сайте

Tags: php, база-данных, интернационализация, mysql

Кто-нибудь мог бы выложить подробную инфу, как реализовать на сайте многоязычность ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Способов реализовать мультиязычность довольно много. Ни что не мешает придумать Вам свой. Выбор того или иного способа зависит от задачи.
Как правило, если для создания сайта используется фреймверк, то в самом фреймверке заложена возможность мультиязычности.

В качестве примера приведу реализацию мультиязычности в django:
1) статический контент в шаблонах оборачивается в специальный тег. Затем фразы, которые были обернуты в тег переводятся в специальном файле (тут я немного упростил, но суть ясна). Затем из запроса берется текущая локаль и выводится соответствующая запись. Если записи нет в файле перевода, то выводится запись по-умолчания, которая стоит в шаблоне.

2) динамический контент (т.е. контент, который хранится в базе). В django есть модуль modeltranslation (возможно попутал название), он делает следующее: создает на каждое переводное поле дополнительные поля (к примеру, есть поле name, этот модель создаст дополнительные поля name_en, name_ru, name_pk и т.п.). Затем модуль смотрит какой язык выбран и выбирает соответствующее поле.

Answer (score 1):

На собственном опыте убедился что лучше создавать отдельные сайты (зеркала, на поддоменах). Отношение поисковых систем тоже будет странным, если одна и та же страничка будет говорить на разных языках. Может возникнуть случай, когда гугл в индексе держит английскую версию сайта, а Яндекс русскую. Это в случае если вы подумаете о выдаче языка с помощью IP-адреса. Конечно если сайт не для поисковых систем, то можете работать.
Не буду голословным, вот посмотрите как реализована многоязыяность на сайте http://www.mp3cut.ru/

Comment: А если доменные имена заняты и удалось выдрать только один? К чему такой пример?

1. Изначально указывается язык который работает дофолтом
2. Кнопка для смены языка испльзуте скрытой способ исполняется от поисковиков из под JavaScript без тега '< a >' а с помощью типа onclick или Jquery '$("#id или .class").click(function(){ отправляем на страницу где запишит куку и сессию с нужным языком; }); Это исключает что поисковик простой див воспримет как ссылку и использует его в качестве получения новых данных. А значит что индексация сайта на EN или DE уже исключена.

Comment: Последние утечки секретной информации через Яндекс доказывают обратное. А как же продвигать сайт в русском сегменте? Самый деловой вариант http://en.site.ru/ http://site.ru/  http://de.site.ru/